# Can I have global preprocessor definitions in C# library?

Tags: c#, .net, c-preprocessor

In C# you can have conditional compilation by using macros similar to the **C**/C++ syntax. This would enable the following to happen:

```
#define MYMACRO
....
#if MYMACRO
//some C# code logic 
#else
//some other C# code logic
```

I need to define some macros in a dedicated file in a C# library project, and I need these macros to be visible inside the entire library, once defined. The problem is that the above code works only for a single file.

Another way I know to work around this, is to add the macros to the build command. This would take care of defining the macros for the entire `.dll` and I will have the `#if - #else` checks working wherever I want inside the library. The issues with this approach is that I want to be able to maintain the macros easily. Having them in a file inside the project will be perfect. I'd like to have some comments inside too, so that I will know what each macro is doing. This will not be applicable if I have to pass the macros as build parameters. Another reason is being able to turn a macro on/off by simply commenting it and examining the behavior.

Is there a decent way to achieve my requirement? I'd prefer not to deal with any build automation tools like `MSBuild`, `NAnt` or anything like this, still if no other way is possible I'd appreciate an advice which one you consider a better choice.

Comment: You can add defines to the csproj file....

Comment: Do you mean, as build parameters? If this is what you have in mind, I already mentioned I am not satisfied with this approach right now. If not, I'd be glad if you shared some more information on how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using so many conditional compilation symbols (that's what they are called, they're not really “macros”)? Maybe there is some other way to do what you want.

Comment: I need them to easily turn on/of features of the library that are not affecting the exposed API, but impact its performance in different circumstances. One of the primary reasons is to have separate builds for Mono-based environment and for standard CLR. Using macros would avoid runtime checks that will affect performance and some things might not even be known at runtime. Also it is easier to have pre-configured builds for different environments.

Comment: In that case, I think it would be better to have different implementations in different classes and inject them based on a config file (using an IoC container), that can differ for the different environments. And doing the runtime check once at the start of the application won't affect performance.

Comment: @svick, this is a good solution, but I fear that in my situation it is something I'd like to avoid. DI implies that the consumer of the library should be aware of the environment dependencies and should take care for proper injection - this makes the library not a standalone one and with a tougher requirements. One of the main purposes I am after is not having the consumer code complicated, or dependent upon these "internal" considerations.

Comment: I don't see how is that implied by DI. You can just use it inside your library and not expose it in any way. You can even embed the config file in the generated DLL, or use something like Windsor's Fluent Registration.

Comment: @svick, the last one causes my lib to require the DI framework to also be available. I do not wish to drag 3rd parties along with it.

Comment: You could use Poor Man's DI, or compile a lightweight container as part of your project. [Here's one example.](http://ayende.com/blog/2886/building-an-ioc-container-in-15-lines-of-code) That would not be my preferred solution, but it's an option.

Comment: @TrueWill, thanks for the useful information, I might take it into account for some other cases, but currently I'd like to stay away from DI at all. Still, this 'Poor Man's DI' approach needs some configuration that should happen at runtime, while I need compile-time ready configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also advise putting the macros in the project settings (csproj file) as @Hans Passant suggests.

If you need the defines documented, you could add a documentation file to the solution explaining what the settings mean.

If there aren't too many variants, you could define a new project configuration for each one. That will allow you to pre-configure the necessary list of #defines for each variant, and then simply switch between them from the configuration combo box in the toolbar. If you want to temporarily disable one option, you could duplicate the current configuration and remove the #define, then delete the config later when you've tested it.

The next option I can suggest to make it "easier" (by combining the settings and docs into a single file as you've suggested) would be to use a simple text file (settings + comments) to configure the project, and spend 15 minutes writing a quick c# app to read this file and write the settings it contains into the .csproj file - it's just XML so should be a trivial app to write. You'd be able to easily tweak this file and run your updater app to chnage the project settings. If it's something you will do often, spend 30 minutes on it and add a UI with checkboxes to choose the settings more easily.

The concept you're describing sounds rather odd, though. The point of a library is usually that you have one standardised lump of code that can be shared by many clients, so changing these sort of defines to reconfigure the whole library a lot is not something that I'd expect to need to do very often. Perhaps you have good reasons, but it may be worth reviewing *why* you need to solve this #define problem.

(e.g. If you have lots of customers who need different variants of the "library", the best approach will be to use configurations (described above) to allow you to build all needed variants in a batch build. If you are just trying out lots of different algorithms/techniques then can you redesign chunks of the library so that you can restrict the impact of most #defines to just to a single .cs file so they no longer need to be global? Perhaps the library shouldn't be in a single dll, or a plug-in architecture is needed to allow you to pick and choose the "modules" that are included within the library)

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy, but useful post. I already began to reconsider my approach with preprocessor directives. I do not want to have DI under any form within my library, so I'll try to do something with configuration. Your other suggestion for writing an app that will take a file and add it to the csproj file could aslo be applied as a pre-build command, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

You #define them for an entire project with Project + Properties, Build tab, "Conditional compilation symbols" setting.  This sets the `<DefineConstants>` element in the project file.  You override this property with msbuild by giving it the /property:DefineConstants="MYMACRO" command line option.

Comment: Thanks for this information, but it is not *exactly* what I needed. I need the macros defined in a standard C# file, and yet achieve the same effect as the thing you mentioned. I am starting to believe it may not be possible with the standard capabilities of VS.

Comment: Right, I wouldn't have posted this answer if your preferred approach could work.

Comment: This answer helped me rather than the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

C# “preprocessor” directives don't work the same as C preprocessor directives. The most important difference for you is that there is no equivalent of `#include`. It's not needed under normal circumstances, because C# doesn't have (or need) header files. I don't think what you want is possible, unless you somehow create your own preprocessor or read the file with `#define`s and make them into parameters of msbuild.

But I think it would be easier for you to use more object-oriented approach: encapsulate the different approaches into classes and use them. To specify which one of them to use, you could use dependency injection. That means you would have to ship a DI library along with your library, but I think that's a price worth paying.

Also, this approach would alleviate a problem with conditional compilation: specifying different set of symbols may break the build in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 1):

**Using GUI**

1. Open the project in Visual Studio
2. Right-Click on the project file in the solution explorer go to properties
3. Go to `Build tab` and Make sure you select the `All Configurations` in the configuration drop down
4. Make sure selected the `All Platforms` in `Platform` drop-down
5. Type the `Preprocessor Definitions` you want in the  `Conditional Compilation Symbols` text box separated by semicolon

[image]

**To the Project file**

1. Open the project file in a text editor
2. Copy and paste this code to end of existing `PropertyGroup`

   `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VariableName)'=='VarableValue'">
       <DefineConstants>PDEF1;PDEF2;PDEF3</DefineConstants>
     </PropertyGroup>`
3. If you not required to add a condition, delete the `Condition="'$(VariableName)'=='VarableValue'"` part
4. Save the project file and open from Visual Studio

From: https://codeketchup.blogspot.sg/2018/04/how-to-add-project-level-preprocessor.html